# IIS - mapping default file extensions

Tags: iis, webserver

I can't find anywhere in IIS configuration option to map pages with no extension to my custom extensions, e.g.:

**Example1:**

entering in browser:

```
https://localhost/myapp/mypage1
```

should be mapped to:

```
https://localhost/myapp/mypage1.ext
```

**Example 2:**

entering in browser:

```
https://localhost/myapp/new
```

should be mapped to:

```
https://localhost/myapp/new.ext
```

I have tried to set (in Handler Mappings section) *.* to point the same executable as *.etx does. No luck here. Maybe I should somehow set in in MIME ?

Thanks !

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite please.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I need to check whether I can use this extension.